# How change in DNS entry impacts on premise TFS system

Tags: tfs, dns, tfs-2015

Our organization IT team is planning to change the DNS entries for the servers. The servers includes our on-premise TFS (2015) server too. How does the change of DNS entry impact the current TFS server? Can someone please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS is a system that points a domain name (like: tfsserver.com) to physical IP address. Usually, we access TFS with IP address, server name or DNS friendly name. If IP address, server name or DNS friendly name doesn't change, it should won't affect you access TFS.